# React Native Metro with Expo TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I have a React Native repo I just cloned to my new computer. It was running fine on my older computer. I am trying to run it with Expo Go, and everytime I try to run I get the following error in Metro:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
at Bundler.transformFile

I have tried the following Node versions. Every time I delete node_modules and reinstall:

- 14.18.3
- 16.20.2
- 18.19.0
- 21.6.1

I've run the following versions of React Native:

- 0.72.6
- 0.73.4

None of the solutions seem to work on here since most suggest using versions of Node I've already tried.